# Edit an eps file generated by Tecplot

Tags: postscript

The eps file which contains one simple curve was generated by Tecplot, but I do not have Tecplot in hand now. I remember it is possible to edit it through VI (as we can open the file with VI, and see the structure of the file), I want to know the structure of the file, then I will be able to revise it as I want. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [this](http://www.waltzballs.org/other/linux/vi.html), might help you.

Comment: thanks :). But I think I just find a more relevant link: http://www.tailrecursive.org/postscript/eps.html

Comment: Unless Tecplot generates highly tame output, you aren't going to be able to do anything useful. Postscript is a full programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Read the [EPS Manual](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf) for all the gritty details. (Have no fear! Adobe Manuals are excellently written and well illustrated.)